# Python: встроенная функция dir()

Tags: python

Почему вывод атрибутов класса при помощи встроенной функция `dir()` не содержит такие атрибуты класса, как `class.__bases__` и `class.__mro__`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.

По-русски говоря, `dir()` рекурсивно отображает содержимое атрибута `__dict__` самого класса и всех его суперклассов, но атрибуты `__bases__` и `__mro__` в них не входят, так как относятся не к классу, а к [типу](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#type-objects).